# Evaluating the operator of free photon lagragian

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, photons, operators, quantum-electrodynamics, klein-gordon-equation

I want to evaluate the operator from a free photon Lagrangian as a exercise and arrive into something with the form:

$$L = A_{\mu}O^{\mu \nu}A_{\nu};$$

parting from the free photon lagrangian:

$$L = -\frac{1}{4}F_{\mu \nu}F^{\mu \nu};$$, where $$F_{\mu \nu} = \partial_{\mu}A_{\nu} - \partial_{\nu}A_{\mu};$$

The far I got was writing the lagrangian in this way:

$$L = -\frac{1}{2}[ (\partial_{\nu}A_\mu)(\partial^\nu A^\mu) - (\partial_{\nu}A_\mu)(\partial^\mu A^\nu)]$$
$$= -\frac{1}{2}[ \partial_{\nu}(A_\mu \partial^\nu A^\mu) - A_\mu(\partial_\nu \partial^\nu A^\mu) - \partial_{\nu}(A_\mu \partial^\mu A^\nu) + A_\mu(\partial_\nu \partial^\mu A^\nu)]$$

Could someone give me a insight of next steps?

Comment: Whenever you have a term like $(\partial_\nu A_\mu)(\partial_\nu A^\mu)$ you can integrate by parts to express it as $- A_\mu \partial^2 A^\mu$. By doing manipulations like this you can put all the derivatives on the second $A$. Another way to say this is that you can simply throw away any total derivative terms like $\partial_\nu(A_\mu \partial^\nu A^\mu)$.

Comment: @user1379857 You mean $(\partial_{\nu}A_\mu)(\partial^\nu A^\mu)$?

Throwing the total derivative terms I would have $\frac{1}{2}[ A_\mu(\partial_\nu \partial^\nu A^\mu) - A_\mu(\partial_\nu \partial^\mu A^\nu)] $ and what would I do with the term $A_\mu(\partial_\nu \partial^\nu A^\mu)$? There is a way to change him into the format   $A_\mu  [Something]A_\nu$?

Comment: Yes, there "something" is just needs to use $g^{\mu \nu}$